# Add only new hyperlinks and order according to FileDateTime

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA code:

```
Sub Hyperlink()
Dim objFSO As Object, objFolder As Object, objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("S:\Promigen Orders")
i = 1

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 1)).Select

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
objFile.Path, TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name

Range(Cells(i + 1, 2), Cells(i + 1, 2)) = FileDateTime(objFile)

i = i + 1
Next objFile
End Sub
```

The code works fine, it locates the folder needed, creates a list down of hyperlinks to that file and then next to each hyperlink it also shows that file's last date modified.

My issue is that every time I run the code, it updates from scratch. What I want it to do is only add NEW files (files that have been placed into the folder after the last time I ran the code). I also want the links to always be in the order of last date modified (oldest to newest down).

In other words, it must only add hyperlinks of files not already on my Excel sheet.

How can my code be edited to perform this?

Comment: Your link that gets added to the page - is that in a format that you could just scan those links, then compare to what's in the folder, and then add anything that's not a match?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this will work (or it may give some ideas):

```
Sub Hyperlink()

Dim objFSO As Object, objFolder As Object, objFile As Object, ObjRange As Range

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("S:\Promigen Orders")

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

    ' Find the Object in your list, if it exists.
    Set ObjRange = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ObjRange = Range("A:A").Find(What:=objFile.Name, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' If it does not exist, add it to the list, at the end & create the hyperlink.
    If ObjRange Is Nothing Then
        ' The reason I have so many .End(xlDown)'s is because I can't be sure if you have titles or not, and this may effect where the "last" cell is
        Set ObjRange = Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ObjRange, Address:=objFile.Path, TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name
    End If

    ' In either case, update the file date time value.
    ObjRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = FileDateTime(objFile)

Next objFile

' Sort by Modified Date
With ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B:B"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SetRange Range("A:B"): .Header = xlYes: .MatchCase = False: .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin: .Apply
End With

End Sub
```